How can I check whether my Mac supports 802.11ax (Wi-Fi 6)?
I am hoping to script a query (perhaps a shell command from the terminal app) to find out current hardware capabilities. I don’t want to have to check the tech specs online at Apple (or other source) for each Mac I run this on.
Is there a way to check on my device what wifi standard it supports?

I haven’t checked every single M1 model, but you might be able to assume it’s based on Apple Silicon https://support.apple.com/en-us/111894 the M1 mini had WiFi6.

FWIW, the System Report, Network section, provides details on the supported Wifi modes:
You can access via System Settings>General>About>System Report. OR Apple> System Settings


Also Option-Apple Menu > System Information

Or from the terminal: system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | grep "Supported PHY Modes"

Here's how to do it from Terminal. This answer does require jq to parse the JSON.
Print capabilities
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType -json -detailLevel mini | jq -r '.SPAirPortDataType[0].spairport_airport_interfaces[0].spairport_supported_phymodes'

Just output a boolean true/false if AX mode is supported
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType -json -detailLevel mini |
jq -r '.SPAirPortDataType[0].spairport_airport_interfaces[0].spairport_supported_phymodes | sub("802.11 ";"") | split("/") | index("ax") != null'


just awesome...
